# Jquery form validation - available options

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using form validation from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. Here you set the form validation declaratively by setting the class on the form element.

I cant find the full list of all the classnames which fire validation and would like to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- required
- email
- url
- date
- dateISO
- dateDE
- number
- numberDE
- digits
- creditcard

That's what I found when I [opened up the code (about 2/3 the way down)](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.js)...

Comment: You can give `class="required email"` to trigger both validations, email and required, that you you dont hav eto write the rule in javascript.